# Print only top few rows of data with C++

Tags: c++, std

I am currently doing a project where I need to plot candlestick data. However, my output gives out all the data that it causes me to be unable to scroll up to my header. Is there any way I can just limit my output to a range, printing only the top few data?

These are my codes

> MerkelMain.cpp

```
#include "MerkelMain.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "OrderBookEntry.h"
#include "CSVReader.h"
#include "Candlestick.h"


void MerkelMain::printCandlestickData()
{
    // std::cout << "MerkelMain::printCandlestickData" << std::endl;

    std::vector<OrderBookEntry> orders = orderBook.getOrders(OrderBookType::bid, "ETH/USDT");

    std::vector<Candlestick> candles = Candlestick::calculateCandlesticks(orders);

    Candlestick::printCandlestickTable(candles);
}
```

> Candlestick.h

```
class Candlestick
{
public:
    //properties
    std::string time, product, type;
    double high, low, open, close;

    Candlestick(std::string time,
                std::string product, 
                std::string type, 
                double high, 
                double low, 
                double open, 
                double close);

    void printCandlestick();
    static void printCandlestickTable(std::vector<Candlestick> candles);

    static std::vector<Candlestick> calculateCandlesticks(
        std::vector<OrderBookEntry> entries
    );

};
```

> Candlestick.cpp

```
#include "Candlestick.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

Candlestick::Candlestick(std::string time,
                         std::string product, 
                         std::string type, 
                         double high, 
                         double low, 
                         double open, 
                         double close) : time(time),
                                         product(product),
                                         type(type),
                                         high(high),
                                         low(low),
                                         open(open),
                                         close(close) {}

// task 1
void Candlestick::printCandlestick()
{
    // std::string time, product, type;
    // double high, low, open, close;

    std::cout << time << "\t"
              << product << "\t"
              << type << "\t"
              << high << "\t"
              << low << "\t"
              << open << "\t"
              << close << "\t"
              << std::endl;
}

void Candlestick::printCandlestickTable(std::vector<Candlestick> candles)
{
   // std::cout << "Candlestick::printCandlestickTable" << std::endl;

   std::cout << "time" 
             << "\t" 
             << "product" 
             << "\t" 
             << "type" 
             << "\t"
            << "high" 
            << "\t" 
            << "low" 
            << "\t" 
            << "open" 
            << "\t" 
            << "close"
            << std::endl;

    for (Candlestick &  candle : candles) {
        candle.printCandlestick();
    }
}
```

This is my output. I can't see my header/ labels and am unable to scroll to the top of the data output. Would really appreciate some help thank you

[image]

Comment: Don't use tabs to separate data.  A tab can represent 2, 3, 4, or 8 spaces.  A tab can represent the spaces of the next "tab stop".   Better to use [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and also `std::left` or `std::right`.

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain words. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: *Is there any way I can just limit my output to a range* -- Yes there is, the problem is that I see no calls to `printCandlestick()` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: In the code that I write, I provide a method that will output the header row.  In more complex code, the column order is adjustable.  You may want to implement something like that.

Comment: hi, so sorry I just updated the code, missed out on 1

Comment: @Nicole *I can't see my header/ labels and am unable to scroll to the top of the data output.* -- What if there are thousands of rows?  Is your goal to print the header once, and then print all the rows?  Or is it to print the header, print ten (or so) rows, then print the header, print the next 10 rows, etc.?

Comment: Your current code prints a single header row, but again, what if there are hundreds or maybe thousands of rows?  What if the console doesn't have a buffer big enough to allow scrolling up to the header row?  You probably need to adjust your code to do as @ThomasMatthews and I suggested in the previous comments.

Comment: *"Is there any way I can just limit my output to a range, printing only the top few data?"*  -- How would you specify the range? Add that to your code as a first step. The second step is to describe (in words) how that specification should be used (at a high, algorithmic level, not necessarily code yet).

Comment: For this question, you might as well drop all the candlestick properties except one. You're asking about rows, not columns, so one column should be sufficient to demonstrate the issue. (Leave a comment somewhere in the code indicating that other columns have been omitted for simplicity.)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the first *n* items in a container using ranges (C++20):

```
using namespace std::views;
const int n = 10;
for (auto& candle : candles | take(n)) {
    /* ... */
}
```